# How to save chart1 in MS SQL as Image using VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net

I was wondering what is the proper code in saving chart1 as image to ms sql using vb.net.

Here is my Code:

```
 Dim cmd2 As New SqlCommand("INSERT INTO OP_ChartImage (DQIR_ID,Chart_Image)values(@dqir,@chart)", conn) 
        Dim img As New Bitmap(Chart1.Width, Chart1.Height)
        Chart1.DrawToBitmap(img, New Rectangle(Point.Empty, img.Size))

        cmd2.Parameters.Add("@chart", SqlDbType.Image).Value = img.RawFormat

        cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dqir", nud_dqirno.Value)

        conn.Open()
        cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery()

        conn.Close()
```

Comment: `Bitmap.RawFormat` is a Guid. You should pass the Image object. I suggest not to use the `SqlDbType.Image` type, store the raw bytes or a Base64 encoded string instead. To store the raw bytes, use the `Bitmap.Save()` method , with a MemoryStream as the `Stream` argument and the `Bitmap.RawFormat` as the `ImageFormat` argument, or another format of choice (avoid JPG in this context -> not directly handling the Encoder parameters). Then save `[MemoryStream].ToArray()`.

Comment: can you give me an example for this?

Comment: If you define your `Chart_Image` field as `VARBINARY(MAX)`,  then `cmd2.Parameters.Add("@chart", SqlDbType.VarBinary, -1).Value = [MemoryStream].ToArray()`. If `-1` truncates the byte array, change it to `Int32.MaxValue`.

Comment: i am using `Chart_Image` field as `IMAGE`

Comment: `Chart1.BackgroundImage.Save(ms, Chart1.BackgroundImage.RawFormat)
        Dim data As Byte() = ms.GetBuffer()
        Dim p2 As New SqlParameter("@chart", SqlDbType.Image)
        p2.Value = data
        cmd.Parameters.Add(p)`

Comment: but still it has an error chart1.backgroundimage is not allowed

Comment: 1) Change the Field type to `VARBINARY(MAX)` (for your convenience, read about it). 2) I explicitly wrote `[MemoryStream].ToArray()`, not `[MemoryStream].GetBuffer()` (never use that) 3) Use the [Chart.SaveImage()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.chart.saveimage) method

Comment: is this right?   
        `Dim xxx As New Bitmap(Chart1.Width, Chart1.Height)
        Dim ms As New MemoryStream
        Dim img As New Bitmap(Chart1.Width, Chart1.Height)
        img.Save(ms, img.RawFormat)
        cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dqir", nud_dqirno.Value)
        Dim data As Byte() = ms.ToArray
        Dim p2 As New SqlParameter("@chart", SqlDbType.Image)

        p2.Value = data
        conn.Open()
        cmd.Parameters.Add(p)
        cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery()
        conn.Close()`

Comment: i try your method but it has error with this   `Dim ms As New MemoryStream

        Dim img As New Bitmap(Chart1.Width, Chart1.Height)img.Save(ms, img.RawFormat)`

Comment: You didn't try what I posted, you tried a mix of your code and pieces of what I posted. You cannot do that. Choose one method (field set to `VARBINARY(MAX)`) or the other (fields set to `Image` type).